# Show that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}{A_{\epsilon}(x_0,y_0) - u(x_0,y_0)\over\epsilon^2} = {1\over 4}\Delta u(x_0,y_0)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

The problem is from Gamelin exercise X.2.2

> Assume that $u(x,y)$ is twice continuously differentiable function on a domain $D$. For $(x_0,y_0)\in D$, let $A_{\epsilon}(x_0,y_0)$ be the average of $u(x,y)$ on the circle centered at $(x_0,y_0)$ of radius $\epsilon$. Show that
> $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}{A_{\epsilon}(x_0,y_0) - u(x_0,y_0)\over\epsilon^2} = {1\over 4}\Delta u(x_0,y_0),$$
> where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator

Hint is to use taylor expansion. Using the second order expansion,
$$u(x,y) = u(x_0,y_0)+(x-x_0)u_x(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)u_y(x_0,y_0)+{1\over 2!}((x-x_0)^2u_{xx}(x_0,y_0)+2(x-x_0)(y-y_0)u_{xy}(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)^2u_{yy}(x_0,y_0)) + o(||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||^2).$$
Now, $A_\epsilon(x_0,y_0) = {1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(z_0+\epsilon e^{i\theta}) d\theta$ where $z_0 = x_0+iy_0$. I think in the limit, enough to consider $(x-x_0)u_x(x_0,y_0)+\cdots+ (y-y_0)^2u_{yy}(x_0,y_0)$ term but no idea what to do next. Please help.

Comment: Hint: Use symmetry to compute the terms in the integral and the show the that first order terms are $0$ and so is the cross term in the second order term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can assume that $(x_0, y_0) = (0, 0)$ and that $u(0, 0) = 0$.

Writing $U_x, U_y, U_{xx}, \ldots $ as a shorthand for $u_x(0, 0), u_y(0, 0), u_{xx}(0, 0), \ldots$ we have

$$
 u(\epsilon \cos(t), \epsilon \sin(t)) 
= \epsilon \cos(t) U_x + \epsilon \cos(t) U_y \\
+ \frac12 \left( \epsilon^2\cos^2(t)U_{xx} + 2\epsilon^2 \cos(t) \sin(t) U_{xy} + \epsilon^2 \sin^2(t)U_{yy}\right) + o(\epsilon^2) \, .
$$

When this is integrated for $0 \le t \le 2 \pi$ then the terms involving $U_x, U_y, U_{xy}$ vanish, so that
$$
 A_\epsilon(0, 0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left( 
 \frac 12 \epsilon^2 U_{xx} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2(t) dt + 
 \frac 12 \epsilon^2 U_{yy} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sin^2(t) dt + o(\epsilon^2)\right) \, .
$$
Both integrals evaluate to $\pi$, and we get
$$
 A_\epsilon(0, 0) = \epsilon^2 \left(\frac{U_{xx}+U_{yy}}{4} + o(1)\right) \, .
$$
The desired conclusion now follows immediately.